# Gallery + Instagram API

Tags: api, gallery

I want to make gallery on my website with photo from Instagram.
Just show my photos. How can I do this without some request like:

```
<_a_ href="https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=<?php echo clientID; ?>&redirect_uri=<?php echo redirectURI; ?>&response_type=code">LOGIN<_a_>
```

Can I define `access_token` for this request?

```
$url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/' . $userID . '/media/recent/?access_token=' . $access_token . '&count=50';
```